# how to fix this app may harmfull play protect

Tags: android, keystore, signature, google-play-protect

I have released an app manually ( not in play store ) 1 years ago.

But recently google play protect show when i want to update my app

Warning: "Blocked by play protect / This app may be harmful"

I removed unnecessary app permissions and sent the app to Google Play Protect Appeals Submission Form twice but nothing changed !!

Is there a possibility that Google blocked the Package name or keystore?

I have many users, what should I do?

Comment: Same problem with me too